# Am I using MATCH() correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this SQL query that keeps shooting me an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OR `description` IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY `datetime` ASC LIMIT 0,20' at line 4

This is the query I'm attempting to run:

```
$items = $itemsClass->getAll($start , $limit, " `status` = 'active' AND MATCH (".sql_quote($s).") AGAINST (`name` OR `description` IN BOOLEAN MODE) ".$whereQuery, "$order");
```

Why: I'm working on a search function for a website and when we search for a certain keyword (i.e. cake), it shows the relavent items. But, when we search for 'cook' which is also in the same title/ description as the cake item, it doesn't result any results and says it's empty.

I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting this error for the query. I'm just trying to find a solution to my problem. I'm using MySQL 5.1.66.

Comment: Please post the _query_, without the PHP-ness. You can abstract the PHP away to leave just the actual MySQL query that you're running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you put column names in the `MATCH()` function, and patterns in the `AGAINST()` function.  You're doing it the wrong way around.

Second, searches across multiple columns are implicitly "OR" comparisons, in that a keyword match in *any* of the indexed columns counts as a match.

So you should use:

```
... MATCH (`name`, `description`) AGAINST (".sql_quote($s).") IN BOOLEAN MODE)"
```

The columns you name in the `MATCH()` function must be all the columns you defined in your fulltext index, and in the same order as they appear in the index.

Only if you defined two *separate* fulltext indexes, one for each column, then you need to use two separate predicates.

```
... MATCH (`name`) AGAINST (".sql_quote($s).") IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    OR 
    MATCH (`description`) AGAINST (".sql_quote($s).") IN BOOLEAN MODE)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
MATCH ("your string") AGAINST (`name` OR `description` IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

However, `AGAINST` (like other operators) is not [associative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property) in this fashion. The expression it takes is just that — an expression; the use of connectives such as `OR` is not unwrapped to apply to the wider operation, but used simply to evaluate to the final expression.

So, usually, you must place the connective `OR` *outside* the operator call:

```
MATCH ("your string") AGAINST `name` IN BOOLEAN MODE
 OR
MATCH ("your string") AGAINST `description` IN BOOLEAN MODE
```

However, in this instance you also switched [the operands to `MATCH`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//fulltext-search.html#function_match).

Write:

```
MATCH (`name`) AGAINST "your string" IN BOOLEAN MODE
 OR
MATCH (`description`) AGAINST "your string" IN BOOLEAN MODE
```

And it so happens that `MATCH` inherently supports searching multiple columns.

---

So, finally:

```
MATCH (`name`, `description`) AGAINST "your string" IN BOOLEAN MODE
```

*The moral of the story is that the documentation is your friend.*

Comment: Apparently the documentation wasn't my friend today as it was the first place I looked. :) Thanks for the help though.